# Get doubletap coordinates in c# windows phone 8

Tags: c#, canvas, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying my best to get the coordinates of where my finger doubletapped when i doubletapped somewhere on the canvas, how can i accomplish this? I have a doubletap method like this:

```
        private void App_DoubleTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get coordinates(left and top) of where i doubletapped
    }
```

Please help me and thanks a lot in advance!:)

Answer (score 1):

To get the position relative to the page, use:

```
Point point=e.GetPosition(this);
```

To get the position relative to the canvas (with the double Tap event regitered on the Canvas), use:

```
point = e.GetPosition(sender as UIElement);
```